# 2D sprite face the direction it's moving in Pygame

Tags: python, sprite, pygame, direction

I'm just learning Python and Pygame and have been working on a very simple game where you play a mouse that has to avoid snakes that spawn every 8 seconds and roam across the screen. Right now I'm trying to get my mouse sprite to face the direction it's moving. The image has the mouse facing down, and I've tried a couple ideas on how to get it to face the right direction but nothing has worked, was hoping someone here could help me out.

Here's the code, no collision detection just yet but the basic code for the mouse is still there.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Imports
import os, sys, math
import pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *

#Sets path for game images
main_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
data_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, 'data')

pygame.init()

#Main screen and background
width, height = 1000, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Don't Get Eaten")
background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(data_dir, 'liquid.bmp'))
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (width, height)) 
screen.blit(background, (0,0))

#Game time setup
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 8000)

#Functions to assist in image loading
def load_image(file):
    file = os.path.join(data_dir, file)
    surface = pygame.image.load(file)
    return surface.convert_alpha()

def load_images(*files):
    imgs = []
    for file in files:
        imgs.append(load_image(file))
    return imgs

#Class for player mouse
class Mouse(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 6
    def __init__(self):
        image = load_image('mouse.png')
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (60,60))
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.groups)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.rect.center = (width/2, height/2)
        self.area = surface.get_rect()

    def movex(self, directionx):
        self.rect.move_ip(directionx*self.speed, 0)

    def movey(self, directiony):
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -directiony*self.speed)        

    def update(self):
        pass

#Class for the snake enemy
class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.groups)
        image = load_image(random.choice(['snake1.png','snake2.png','snake3.png']))
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (85,85))
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = surface.get_rect()
        self.movex = random.randint(1,5)
        self.movey = random.randint(1,5)

    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.movex,self.movey)
        if self.rect.left < self.area.left or self.rect.right > self.area.right:
            self.movex = -self.movex
            newpos = self.rect.move((self.movex, 0))
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, 1, 0)
            self.rect = newpos
        if self.rect.top < self.area.top or self.rect.bottom > self.area.bottom:
            self.movey = -self.movey
            newpos = self.rect.move((0, self.movey))
            self.rect = newpos




#Pregame setup
allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
snakesprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mousesprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
Snake.groups = allsprites, snakesprites
Mouse.groups = allsprites, mousesprites
mouse = Mouse()
snake = Snake()

def main():
    #Main game loop
    while 1:    

        #Setup and blits        
        seconds = clock.tick()/1000.0
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))

        #Game events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == USEREVENT+1:
                Snake()
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        directionx = keystate[K_RIGHT] - keystate[K_LEFT]
        directiony = keystate[K_UP] - keystate[K_DOWN]
        mouse.movex(directionx)
        mouse.movey(directiony)

        allsprites.update()
        allsprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip
        clock.tick(60)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the mouse look into the right direction, I'd try [pygame.transform.rotate](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) and make the degrees of rotation depend on the `directionx` and `directiony` variables being greater or less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is some sample code from one of my projects, it uses trigonometry to rotate the image.

```
    self.deltaX = pos[0] - des[0]
    self.deltaY = pos[1] - des[1]
    self.angle = math.atan2(self.deltaX, self.deltaY) *180 / math.pi

    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.angle)
```

pos is the (mouse in your case)'s position, and 'des' it a tuple of it's destination.